# Julia: comparing strings with special characters

Tags: string, julia

I need to read a text file which contains `csv` data with headers separating individual blocks of data. The headers always start with the dollar sign `$`. So my text file looks like:

```
$Header1
2
1,2,3,4
2,4,5,8
$Header2
2
1,1,0,19,9,8
2,1,0,18,8,7
```

What I want to do is if the program reaches to `$Header2`, I want to read all the next lines following it till it reaches, say, `$Header3` or end of the file. I think I can use `cmp' in Julia for this. I tried with a small file that contains following text:

```
# file julia.txt
Julia
$Julia
```

and my code reads:

```
# test.jl
fname = "julia.txt"
# set some string values
str1 ="Julia";
str2 ="\$Julia";
# print the strings and check the length
println(length(str1),",",str1);
println(length(str2),",",str2);
# now read the text file to check if you are able to find the strings
# str1 and str2 above
println ("Reading file...");
for ln in eachline(fname)
 println(length(ln),",",ln);
 if (cmp(str1,ln)==0)
  println("Julia match")
 end
 if (cmp(str2,ln)==0)
  println("\$Julia match")
 end
end
```

what I get as output from the above code is:

```
5,Julia
6,$Julia
Reading file...
6,Julia

7,$Julia
```

I don't understand why I get character length of 6 for string `Julia` and 7 for the string `$Julia` when they are read from the file. I checked the text file by turning on white spaces and there are none. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `if(contains(ln,str1)) println("Julia match") end` seems to be doing the job but simply because length of ln is greater than str1. Though this works perhaps an exact string comparison should still be possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that the strings returned by `eachline` contain a newline character at the end.

You can use `chomp` to remove it:

```
julia> first(eachline("julia.txt"))
"Julia\n"

julia> chomp(first(eachline("julia.txt")))
"Julia"
```

Also, you can simply use `==` instead of `cmp` to test whether two strings are equal. Both use a `ccall` to `memcmp` but `==` only does that for strings of equal length and is thus probably faster.